# Multiple Inputs to Powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am running one script which is asking me multiple inputs like "R" "Y" "IP address". How to make this automate .How can I pass R and after that again R then IP address ? I have tried few example on web but its not working ...

```
1) PS C:\orchestrator\scripts> ./Install-Orchestrator.ps1 echo "Y`r" | pw
2)./Install-Orchestrator.ps1 |echo R
3).powershell.exe -noexit -file 'Install-Orchestrator.ps1' "R"
```

Below is the script and options

```
PS C:\orchestrator\scripts> ./Install-Orchestrator.ps1

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run C:\orchestrator\scripts\Install-Orchestrator.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): R
---------------------------------

  UiPath Orchestrator v2 Installer

---------------------------------

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run C:\orchestrator\scripts\Test-FrameworkVersion.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): R
Checking current version of .NET
Current .NET version installed  4.7
You have correct version of .NET: (4.7)

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run C:\orchestrator\scripts\Test-WebDeployVersion.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): R
Checking current version of Web Deploy
You have correct version of Web Deploy  3.1237.1764

Do you want to test port to database?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [?] Help (default is "N"): Y
Testing open port to database

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run C:\orchestrator\scripts\Test-PortOpen.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): R
Enter the host/ip address: 10.10.10.100
Enter the port number to access: 1433
```

Comment: Does it have a force operator?

Comment: You need to change your ExecutionPolicy if you're talking about the security warning.  Throw this into a batch script (`script.cmd` or `script.bat`):  `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File 'path\to\script.ps1'`

Comment: Take a look in the docu ;) https://orchestrator.uipath.com/v2016.2/docs/orchestrator-server-installation

Comment: PS C:\orchestrator\scripts> powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Install-Orchestrator.ps1

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run C:\orchestrator\scripts\Install-Orchestrator.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"):

Comment: So run `Unblock-File` on the script, like it says. Or use the `Bypass` execution policy rather than `Unrestricted`. (Run `help about_Execution_Policies` and read. `Unrestricted` does not do what you think it does.)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - have a read on execution policies. I think you mean `Bypass` rather than `Unrestricted`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Does it really matter?

Comment: Yes, in this case it happens to matter, based on the prompt the OP is seeing. (Hence my recommendation.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Followed your advice.  I always had the mentality that it was like the SilentlyContinue vs Ignore situation in that they were the same.  Most of my scripts do automation so I never had a difference.  Thanks for the read.  For those that stumble upon this: Bypass has no prompts, no warnings, etc. while Unrestricted will warn you if the script was downloaded from an 'Internet source'

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Now you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Create a text file with the inputs like below

some_text_file.txt
R
Y
10.0.0.123

Then run the below command in Powershell

```
Start-Process -FilePath "./Install-Orchestrator.ps1" -ArgumentList "if there are any" -Wait -RedirectStandardInput "./some_text_file.txt"
```